# Handling of calculated vs input parameters in bw2

Tags: brightway

In `Simapro` there is a distinction between `*Input parameters` (i.e. fixed amount) and `*Calculated parameters` (i.e. equations)...with `*` that could be activity, project or databases.

Is there a similar distinction in `bw2.data.parameters` or not...being cleared for the second I mean that  each activity, project and/or database parameters is/should be treated/imported in the same manner. For example, `bw2data.parameters.ProjectParameter` includes both what would be in Sima `Project Input parameters` and `Project Calculated parameters`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question, and should be better addressed in the documentation. In Brightway, there is no distinction - any named parameter can be either a fixed value, an uncertainty distribution, or calculated using a formula.

Comment: This can be a tricky story when dealing with Sima import. From what I got from the documentation, `bw2data.parameters` works with groups that does not allow for circular references and each list of db or project parameters is a separate bw2 group. But in sima there can be circular references between them e.g.  `Project Calculated parameters` can depend on `Database Input parameters` and the other way around. This might need to review the default name given to projects and databases names.

Comment: Please check and make sure that this is correct - a global namespace just seems insane! Then there is no difference between project and database parameters?